# List should be clicked on button Hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have created one DIV with button and list.I want when I Hover on button, list should display as well as I  can click on items in List. currently list displaying on button hover but when I want some List item to clicked its Disappearing .

My Html is

```
<div id="rentin">
            <button id='rentInbutton'>Buy/Rent In</button> 
          <ul>
                  <li><a href="Accomodation.do?action=rin">Accomodation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="VehiclesRentIn.do?action=rin">Vehicles</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

And my Jquery Code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $('#rentin ul').hide();
             $("#rentInbutton").hover(function(){
                     $('#rentin ul').show();},function(){
                       $('#rentin ul').hide();
});
}  )
```

Comment: If you can, attach the `hover()` to `#rentin`: `$("#rentin").hover(....` http://jsfiddle.net/wrqgn1oz/ It depends on the layout of your UI whether or not this is appropriate for you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are hiding the UL when the mouse leaves the button, instead you should hide it only when the mouse leaves the UL or its container - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7cbzh2n/1/)

```
$("#rentInbutton").mouseover(function(){
    $('#rentin ul').show();
});
$('#rentin').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#rentin ul').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hover `retin` instead of hovering `retinInButton` because button and list is inside `retin` and initially when list is hidden `retin` area is almost equal to button area and when list is visible then `retin` will take space equal to button plus list and you will not loose list because mouse pointer is still inside `retin`, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#rentin ul').hide();
        $("#rentin").hover(function(){
           $('#rentin ul').show();},function(){
          $('#rentin ul').hide();
        });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xt8db6zf/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rentin ul').hide();
    $("#rentInbutton").hover(function() {
        $('#rentin ul').show();
    });
})
```